# android wear : how to store data in WearableListenerService and access them?

Tags: java, android, service, wear-os

I am a java/android beginner, trying to develop a simple wear app.

I am using a WearableListenerService to listen for data change from the handset and display these data on the wearable.
These data represent the user context, let's say the number of beers he has drunk in the past 5 minutes.
So, I have a `int beerContext` on the Handset and on the Watch that I'm trying to synchronize so that display on the watch and on the handset is the same.

As long as the number of beers is set from the handset **only**, everything is fine. Thanks to the data events gathered by the WearableListenerService.

**BUT** : I would like to make a little UI on the watch so that the user can update its number of beers drank.

**My question is** : the numberOfBeers is a private variable of the WearableListenerService. How can a watch activity update this variable as I didn't find any way to get a reference to the WearableListenerService? (I tried to override the onBind method, but it is final, so that's impossible.

I would very appreciate some precious advices as I might have done mistake in my app design.

A big thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding how the data communication between the wear/phone works.

Each app will need to implement its own WearableListenerService, and each app will need to send data to the other app through the data api. Your private variable has no effect - theres no way to access this from the other app.

Have a read through [Syncing Data items](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html).

When sending the beer count from either the phone app or the wear app, you will need to send it with the data api:

e.g.

```
PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/beerCount");
dataMap.getDataMap().putInt(BEER_COUNT_KEY, beerCount);
PutDataRequest request = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();
PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult = Wearable.DataApi
    .putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, request);
```

You will then get notified in the WearableListenerService when that data is received.

Comment: The thing is that I want this beerCount to be accessed by an Activity. For example, onDataChanged {this.beerCount=receivedBeerCount;myNotifManager.notify(xxx,notif)}
With notif embedding a pendingIntent to open BeerCountActivity.class
IF the User click on this Notif, I would like the Activy to launch and get beerCount from the WearableListenerService and display it!

Comment: In that case, you would need to integrate messages as well. The activity would start and send a message using the data api to the phone/wear app requesting an updated beer count. The receiving app would then send the beer count using the data api data item (or you could even use a message for that too).

Have a read through [messages](http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/messages.html)

Instead of using a wearable listener service, you can use a DataListener inside your activity.